# Find the value of the integral $\int _C ze^{\frac{3}{z}}dz $.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $C$ be the contour $|z|=2$ oriented in the anti-clockwise direction.Find the value of the integral $\int _C ze^{\frac{3}{z}}\ \mathrm dz $.

**My try**:Here $z=0$  is  an essential singularity of the function. Putting $z=2e^{i\theta}$.Then

$$\int _C ze^{\dfrac{3}{z}}\ \mathrm dz =\int _0^ {2\pi} 2e^{i\theta}e^{\dfrac{3}{2e^{i\theta}}}\ \mathrm d\theta$$.

Next I tried substituting $t=e^{i\theta}$ but then the limits become $0$ in both cases.
What should I do now?

Comment: Try using the Laurent series.of the exponential.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nasty singularity at $z=0$, so I would substitute $z=1/w$, $dz=-dw/w^2$, and get $$-\int_{C'}e^{3w}w^{-3}dw$$
where $C'$ is a circle, radius $1/2$, travelled clockwise.

Comment: Now $e^{3w}w^{-3}$ has a pole of order $3$ at $w=0$.Hence by Residue Theorem it will be $-9\pi i$ ; is it correct?

Comment: There is a minus sign, and the direction is now clockwise, so I think it is $+9\pi i$.